# Firebase user auth state logic

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

After signing a user in with Firebase, for how long will he stay as signed-in ? I mean for example , what happens when application is not visible or destroyed ? Does firebase automaticly log that user out? Or do I need to write that logic myself?

Answer (score 1):

From official documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/users#the_current_user

> When a user signs up or signs in, that user becomes the current user
>   of the Auth instance. **The Firebase Auth instance persists the user's
>   state**, so that refreshing the page (in a browser) or **restarting the
>   application doesn't lose the user's information.**
>
> When the user signs out, the Auth instance stops keeping a reference
>   to the User object and no longer persists its state; there is no
>   current user. However, the user instance continues to be completely
>   functional: if you keep a reference to it, you can still access and
>   update the user's data.

So you have to manually sign out the user by using `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut()` method.

This implementation is very smart because this way you  do not have to manage user "session" but you have only to implemente signout where needed!

Comment: So user is still signed in when application is closed , we don't want that. I'm thinking of extending the application class and calling signOut method in onDestroy , would that be a good idea? application class has a onDestroy method right?

Comment: this depends on your requirements, generally force the user to login every time is very stressfull. No forget onDestroy because is not call always..signout always before login method so you are sure that if user is logged firs you force logout and the go to login

Comment: What i need is simple . If the user status is logged in when the application stops ,  i want user to log out automaticly. Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: Because my project is something like whatsapp, users shouldnt be seen as online if my app isnt visible on screen

Comment: use firebase database to track user status

Comment: @user6650650 I think you're looking at it wrong. A user being signed in or signed out is different from being 'online' or 'offline'. What you want to do is keep the user signed in, but have a way to keep track of wether they are connected to the database or not. See this guidance on Managing Presence: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence

Answer (score 0):

You need to write that logic yourself, just write:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
```